# Joomla 3 set default template programmatically for component

Tags: templates, joomla, components

Is it possible to set a template programmatically for a component?

Comment: https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/advancedtemplatemanager this extension does it perfectly for free

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some really valid reason why it needs to be done programmatically, you can simply do it via the Joomla Template Manager:

**Joomla Backend** >> **Extensions** >> **Template Manager**

If you open up you desired templates, you can assign each one to different menu items and of course each menu item will have a component assigned to it.

This is the simplest approach.

Comment: Thx, but there are a lot of views and only less menue items, so this approach is more for normal websites.

Answer (score 0):

Not a 100% if you want to do this site wide or for a specific template layout override.  I'm assuming with my first attempt at this answer I'll assume you would like this done site wide.

To accomplish with code.  First, register the required classes:

```
    JLoader::register('TemplatesTableStyle', JPATH_ROOT . '/administrator/components/com_templates/tables/style.php');
    JLoader::register('TemplatesModelStyle', JPATH_ROOT . '/administrator/components/com_templates/models/style.php');
```

Second, get the model object and set a new default template using Joomla's core:

```
    $model = JModel::getInstance('style', 'TemplatesModel');
    $model->setHome($template_id);
```

Good luck!

Comment: why do you suggest to go over Joomla model? Would there be no direct way?

Comment: Short answer is because this is the way Joomla does it when you change the template through the back end GUI.  One of the major benefits of using a framework like Joomla is utilizing the host of already implemented functionality in the core.  You could hand roll a method to manually alter the DB tables for the current and future default table, but why when the code already exists!  And I guarantee the lines required to perform those custom DB edits will be far greater the 4 to leverage the core classes.  :)

Comment: sounds like a method, which can lead to success. Where are you implementing the class registering and the model object, for site wide using?